# In matlab, how to convert a list of points to a binary matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

How would a list of points be converted to a binary matrix? Hopefully the operation will perform  suitably for 640x640 images. Here is an example:

```
% the points
p = [2 2;2 3;3 3]

% the images is 4x4
img=zeros(4,4)

% set img to 1 for all points in p
```

??? this is the question?

% resulting binary image
img =

```
 0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0
 0     1     1     0
 0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
linearInd = sub2ind(size(img), p(:,2), p(:,1));
img(linearInd) = 1;
```

Comment: Both answers are the same. I didn't know an image could be set by a linear index. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
img(sub2ind(size(img), p(:,2), p(:,1))) = 1;
```

**For example:**

```
p = [2 2;2 3;3 3];
img = zeros(4,4);

img(sub2ind(size(img), p(:,2), p(:,1))) = 1
```

This would give you:

```
img =

   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0
   0   1   1   0
   0   0   0   0
```